# Search and Index Office 365 elements

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-search

Is it possible to setup SharePoint Online Search to index Office 365 elements (like Planner plans, tasks, OneDrive, groups calendars, groups emails / conversations...)? If so, is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to setup SharePoint Online Search to index Office 365 elements. Below is a link which provides you the new feature of search

https://blogs.office.com/2016/04/13/introducing-a-new-home-page-experience-for-office-365-users/

You will get three search sources here:

SharePoint Sites

One drive

Links & attachments in Email

Please see below image for reference:
[image]

I dint get any specific link which provides all elements in single search. But hope this fixed maximum of your requirements.

Let me know if you have any other query and contact us for [SharePoint Consulting](http://www.binaryrepublik.com) at www.BinaryRepublik.com

Comment: I think the link is wrong...nothing in there about search. And I am curious also if there is in plan to index graph somehow and allow custom search solutions based on this.

Comment: Added my search results when I searched using the added feature. You can see results of SharePoint site and One drive there.